# What is the optimal chunk size to send over http?

Tags: node.js, http, stream

I have to send data over http, server to server, with this basic kind of code :

```
const http = require('http')
const someBigData = require('./bigDataSource')

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.write(someBigData)
  res.end()
}).listen(8080)
```

The thing is, `someBigData` can be VERY big.
So my question is, what is the optimal size for a chunk ?

Comment: is the total size of `someBigData` known in advance?

Comment: No, unpredictable size ! More fun that way.

Comment: so i suspect the implementation would use [chunked encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). If that's the case, then any chunk size that would overwhelm any overhead introduced by chunk headers/ newlines would do. try 2^15 (32KB).

Comment: Any particular reason for 32kB ?

Comment: It should be stated that performance isn't an issue really as long as a chunk is bigger than a kilobyte. It's mostly for compatibility. I can imagine some implementations disliking extremely big chunks but also many small chunks over long periods of time. However i have no evidence of what i just said and i would admit it's for the most part arbitrary.

Comment: Ok thank you for the infos :)
I was also concerned about the network having to deal with big amount of data at once, but setting a check for the size and using your 32kB value should do the trick I guess.